# converting a '[1,2,3,4]' to a float or int in python

Tags: python

Hi so I am trying to find the avg of a list
We have to make a function so I have

```
def avgLst():
    'str==>avg of numbers in str'
    x=input('Please enter a List: ')

    if len(x)==0:
        return([])
```

It is from this point I am having trouble.
I am trying to find to avg of the input we put into the problem.
something like[1,2,3,4] problem is this list is a string because of the input. How do I get the list to be a list of integers or floats to then find the avg of the list?
Thanks,

Comment: How would you do this average on paper?   Also, you're not going to be generating a list from `input`.

Comment: Yeah I know that, The input will be a string, I am trying to make that string into something I can use to do the avg. Once I get the string usable I can do the rest

Comment: very new to python and programming in general

Comment: Also needs to be in a function

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3? In python2, input can return  a list.

Comment: I am using python 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle parsing the `string` data in numerous ways.  I haven't tested this function for speed but one way you could do this is:

```
def list_avg(str_list):
    int_list = [float(i.strip('[]')) for i in str_list.split(',')]
    return sum(int_list) / len(int_list)
```

If I understand correctly what you are asking, then `list_avg` will return a `float` average of the integers in `str_list`.

Comment: if the numbers are two digits this method will not give the intended result

Comment: @RyanBland I've edited my response to account for `floats` too.  `.isdigit()` would not work with your case because if you did have a `float` in your input `.isdigit()` would pull out each digit separately from the data instead of a single `float`.

Comment: Thanks, I just started learning python and programming and could not for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: Sure thing, there are plenty of great resources out there and python has a very helpful community.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` here:

```
In [6]: strs="[1,2,3,4]"

In [7]: from ast import literal_eval

In [9]: literal_eval(strs)
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**help(literal_eval)**:

```
In [10]: literal_eval?
Type:       function
String Form:<function literal_eval at 0x8cb7534>
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py
Definition: literal_eval(node_or_string)
Docstring:
Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
and None.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can process your input as follows:

```
def input_to_list(input_str):
    input_list = input_str[1:-1].split(",")
    return map(int, input_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**literal_eval( )**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)  in [ast (Abstract Syntax Trees)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module :

```
>> import ast

>> yrStrList = '[1,2,3,4]'
>> yrList = ast.literal_eval(yrlist)
>> print yrList

[1,2,3,4]
```

[Detail](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) about `literal_eval( )`